# How to format Android view IDs

Tags: android, coding-standards, conventions

I struggle with this every time I work on a project. I am not entirely sure what the standard conventions are for creating view ids. I usually use something like

```
view_more_button
```

but then if we have, let's say, multiple dialogs with a view more button then I'll start doing

```
view_more_button_dialog1
```

and from there it just spirals downward.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefix resource IDs with the "component" they belong to. Note that I say resource IDs and not View IDs because this applies to other resources too (String for example).

Specifically for views, I further add the view type after the component prefix.

Here's a concrete example:

```
login_button_done (View ID)
login_ok (String resource)
login_forgot_password (String resource)
dialog_button_view_more (View ID)
dialog_label_warning (View ID)
```

One advantage of this approach is it makes it easier for IDE auto-complete. The downside is more keystrokes at the time of creating the views/String resources.

I have seen developers use a convention that puts the prefixes in the other order (i.e., viewtype_component_id). You should pick whatever suits your needs the best and just remember to stick to it throughout.

Not directly related to the question - but for some of my larger applications where the number of resources (especially strings) is very large, I also prefer to split up the strings into multiple files by component. For example, I'd have `strings_login.xml`, `strings_settings.xml` etc.

Specifically for dialogs, your view hierarchy would rarely (never ??) contain two dialogs simultaneously, so it is okay to re-use view IDs. In fact, I do sometimes create a few generic View IDs for this purpose.